# prettify urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried the to solve this by reading similar question from others, but I still do not get it to work properly. 
I am using opencart.com. 
When I view individual product page It comes correctly like: 
/purple-sleeve-sweater
/blue-sleeve-sweater

but when I am looking at all the products under a page I get
    index.php?route=product/category&path=13_15

and also my contact page and blog come out like this
    index.php?route=product/category&path=2
    index.php?route=product/category&path=3

but i could like it to be /contact us and /blog

and my blog post come out like this
    index.php?route=product/category&path=3_16

and yet all individual products come out correctly.

The following is from my .httaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make  sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
#RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).php/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the   following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.
```

What is missing and where so that it creates my page/post name in the url